# Output manipulation from subprocess

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to manipulate the output from a subprocess call and only print specific details. Now I was originally going down the `PIPE` route and piping the output to another `subprocess` of `grep` but this seemed too limiting, meaning I could only print a few lines (some of which I didn't want), by using the `-A` or `-B` `grep` arguments. So now I'm taking the `stdout.readline` route. My question is, is there a better way to do achieve what I am trying to do? Is pattern matching with regular expressions and `re` the best option?

Below is the code for both trails of thought, just to give some context.

**PIPE to another subprocess:**

```
def nmap_ips(ip_list):

    for ip in ip_list:
        cmd1 = subprocess.Popen(["nmap", "-sC", "--open", "-Pn", "-p80,443", ip], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        cmd2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "title", "-A", "1"], stdin=cmd1.stdout)
        cmd1.stdout.close()
        output = cmd2.communicate()[0]
```

**stdout read lines:** #Im not actually getting output from this function at the moment, I'm guessing it's my regex

```
def nmap_ips(ip_list):
   regs = ["title", "commonName"]
   combined = "|".join(regs)

   for ip in ip_list:
      p = subprocess.Popen(["nmap", "-sC", "--open", "-Pn", "-p80,443", ip], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
         ml = re.match(combined, line)
         if ml:
            print ml.group()
```

**Example of data I am trying to manipulate**

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-10 23:47 BST
Nmap scan report for BTHomeHub.home (192.168.1.254)
Host is up (0.0054s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
| http-title: Home Hub Manager - Please Reset Your Password
|_Requested resource was http://BTHomeHub.home/html/home/a_firstlogin_configuration.html
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=bthomehub.home/countryName=UK
| Not valid before: 2011-01-15T16:52:23+00:00
|_Not valid after:  2024-01-17T16:52:23+00:00
|_ssl-date: 2014-10-10T22:47:18+00:00; +14s from local time.
```

Comment: what is the question? Do you see the required output if you use `print line,`? Do you need to debug the regex? Then remove unrelated `subprocess` code and just provide several lines as strings in the code itself as a test input.

Comment: Apologies seems I didn't make myself clear enough. First off, I'm asking for a recommendation on a way to achieve what I'm after. Is the readline method feasible?

Comment: feasible for what? The code reads `b'\n'`-separated lines from `nmap`'s merged stdout/stderr. Is it what you are after? What is the expected result?

Comment: you could set `bufsize=1` to enable buffering.

Comment: Is this a good approach to take to avoid the limitations of using the initial `PIPE` to `stdin` of another `subprocess`. I'm trying to achieve printing lines that contain the pattern matches.

Comment: does it work for you? Do you find the code readable? Is it correct? Is it efficient enough? If all answers are "yes" then yes it is a good approach.

Comment: lol well I've not got it working yet so rather wasting time working out a way to fix it. I thought id ask more experienced coders if they believe I was heading down the right path first.

Comment: I'm guessing its my patterns as I'm not getting any output. Maybe my approach at using the patterns?

Comment: combined prints out as `title|commonName`, if I understand it correctly it should be looking for lines that match `title` or `commonName` and print the line if it does.

Comment: Does `nmap ... | grep 'title\|commonName'` print what you want?

Comment: Yip, I get output when running it in commandline.

Comment: Do you need to save that output as a Python bytestring?

Comment: I haven't a clue what that is. I will google it and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. Both `grep 'title\|commonName'` and `re.search(b'title|commonName', line)` should work.

Note: `re.match()` starts matching at the begining of its input string. `re.search()` finds the match anywhere in the string.

If you want to save these lines in a variable then the `grep` process is unnecessary. It is enough to start only `nmap`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def nmap_something(ip_list):
    match = re.compile(b"title|commonName").search
    p = Popen(["nmap", "-sC", "--open", "-Pn", "-p80,443"] + ip_list,
              stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)
    result = list(filter(match, p.stdout))
    p.stdout.close()
    p.wait()
    return result
```

I'm not sure about the exact syntax to pass multiple ips to a single `nmap` child process but it supports it i.e., you don't need to start multiple processes to scan multiple ips.

If you want to print ssl certificates for web servers then you don't need `nmap`, you could use a pure Python solution e.g., see [How to get server's ssl certificate in a human readable form?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104623/1321)

Comment: The ip passing is not a problem that all works fine. Im not using `grep` in the re matching approach. `grep` was going to be used if I went down the initial `PIPE` to another `subprocess` (would have been grep).

Comment: Using `re.search` I get output but it is only the exact match that is printed lol IE `title` next line `commonName`

Comment: Ok ive got it working. Instead of printing the matching group. I just print the line `if ml:`

Answer (score 0):

After some advice from J.F.Sebastian, I changed to `re.search` and found printing the line directly achieved what I was after.

```
def nmap_ips(ip_list):
    regs = ["title", "commonName"]
    combined = "|".join(regs)

    for ip in ip_list:
        p = subprocess.Popen(["nmap", "-sC", "--open", "-Pn", "-p80,443", ip], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
            ml = re.search(combined, line)
            if ml:
                print line
```